# TypeError: Cannot read property 'subroute' of undefined in JEST and enzyme testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using **jest and enzyme library for react testing** with **create-react-app boilerplate**.

With the running of suite and test I am get in above error..
Could not found any solution yet. 
Let me know if any solution.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subroute' of undefined
```

Comment: Please provide more code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was rendering the `connected component` with passing the props into it.

So with that purpose all we need to pass **store** element into the **Provider**, and mount the component into it.

So all we need to understand is :

***Mount***: It will render the *deep element* of props and component associated with it.

***Shallow***: It will render the the first component of the top layer, not going the deep connected component as I was doing before with shallow.

Here are the code for and complete solution:

```
import { mountWrap } from '../contextWrap'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import Login from '../components/Login/'
// import makeStore from '../redux/createStore'

import React from 'react'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const mockStore = configureMockStore([ thunk ])
const authDetails = {
  'authDetails' : {
    Terms :''
  }
}

const match = {
  params : {}
}
let actionSpy = sinon.spy()
let actionHistorySpy = sinon.stub({})
let authDetails_ = sinon.stub(authDetails)
let store
let component
/* eslint-disable */
describe('tests for MyContainerComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(authDetails)
    component = mountWrap(<Provider store={ store }>
      <Login history={actionHistorySpy} match={match} setGlobalLoaderStatus= {actionSpy} userDetail={authDetails_} />
     </Provider>)
  })

  it('renders container', () => {
    console.log(component.debug())
  })
})
```